# How do I make this SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Quite simply, I need to make a query that prints out all the years (in increasing order) in which only 1 exam took place. I am thinking something along the lines of having to query for every distinct year, and then use the count function to test if there was only one exam in that year? But I can't quite seem to write it out. If it is of importance, the program is being written in Java so I can manipulate outputs.

The form of the EXAM table is:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAM
  (Student_id     char(5),      NOT NULL
   Module_code    varchar(6),     NOT NULL
   Exam_year      smallint,     NOT NULL
   Score        smallint,     NOT NULL
   PRIMARY KEY (Student_id, Module_code)      -- Creates a unique tuple
   FOREIGN KEY (Student_id) REFERENCES STUDENT(Student_id)    -- Enforces data integrity
   FOREIGN KEY (Module_code) REFERENCES MODULE(Module_code)   -- Enforces data integrity
  );
```

Comment: I think each row is a student taking a test. Module would be the class or something similar.

Comment: @Tammert Yes, just saw that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING`, and use `distinct Module_code` just in case.

```
SELECT Exam_year
FROM EXAM
GROUP BY Exam_year
HAVING COUNT(distinct Module_code) = 1
ORDER BY Exam_year
```

Comment: I knew I was missing a keyword! I've just looked up HAVING, it is perfect! Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

`select Exam_year
from EXAM
group by module_code
having count(module_code) = 1
order by Exam_year asc`

Answer (score 1):

One query should get the job done. Try this:

```
select Exam_year
from EXAM 
group by Exam_year
having count(*) = 1
order by Exam_year
```

If you need more information than just Exam_year in the output, this can be modified to support additional info, but this example is the simplest way to do what is stated in your requirement.